# Elastic connection ERROR -> Elasticsearch 6 + Kibana + Docker Compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, xpath, docker-compose, kibana

Below is my docker.compose.yml.

After executing it, it shows:

```
kibana            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-04-24T18:27:43Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
kibana            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-04-24T18:27:43Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
```

I believe the problem might be related to the platinum release of elasticsearch I am excuting, related to the fact I might not be setting the right parameters to use it with Xpath.

Am I forgetting to set up anything to make platinum work?

I tried even going to kitematic and linking manually Kibana to Elasticsearch container but the same problem continues.

Nothing that I tried worked. How can I fix this?

```
   version: '2.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet

  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://localhost:9200"
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
      - "xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled=true"
    ports: 
      - 5601:5601
    networks: 
      - esnet
    depends_on: 
      - elasticsearch  

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Anyone can help?